# Mozilla XUL - Dialog button's ID

Tags: javascript, xul

I'm thinking if there's a way to add ID attributes to 'accept' and 'cancel' buttons within a dialog?

```
<dialog id="myDialog" title="My Dialog"
        xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
        onload="window.sizeToContent();"
        buttons="accept,cancel"
        buttonlabelaccept="Set Favourite"
        buttonaccesskeyaccept="S"
        ondialogaccept="return doSave();"
        buttonlabelcancel="Cancel"
        buttonaccesskeycancel="n"
        ondialogcancel="return doCancel();">
```

I know I can add buttons like this:

```
<button
    id="identifier"
    class="dialog"
    label="OK"
    image="images/image.jpg"
    disabled="true"
    accesskey="t"/>
```

But can be this done inside a dialog context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done inside of a dialog context. But the code you've posted might not work as  expected depending on what you expect to achieve.

The button you posted will not function as the accept button unless it has special attribute `dlgtype="accept"`. Citing [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Dialogs_and_Prompts#Buttons_in_.3Cdialog.3E) that talks about creating custom dialog buttons:

> If you are not satisfied with the layout of predefined buttons in dialog, you can put explicit button elements in your XUL file and add a dlgtype attribute to them. Valid values for dlgtype are the six button types listed above.

```
<button
    dlgtype="accept"
    class="dialog"
    label="OK"
    image="images/image.jpg"
    disabled="true"
    accesskey="t"/>
```

This approach enables you to choose where the accept button is located, styling of it etc.

---

If the goal is to get an accept button somewhere in the code and manipulate its properties, then just use `document.documentElement.getButton("accept")`. Citing the same article:

```
// Disable the OK and Cancel btns
document.documentElement.getButton("accept").disabled = true;
document.documentElement.getButton("cancel").disabled = true;
```

Let me know if you wanted something different.